# Calling method from different class (different than other questions)

Tags: java

So I'm relatively new to java and I'm trying to use a method from a different class inside my main.

The method I'm using to pull doesn't contain any data initially but pulls the data from a text doc.

I've included the code that calls the other class method that loads the data from the file. It sill doesn`t work, so where is my mistake?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalRobert {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//output of animalList class here 
}
```

Here is the class I'm trying to pull from:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class animalList {

public void animalDetails () {

int i = 0;

String animalInfo = "C:/Users/Robert/Documents/animals.txt";
String animalHabitat = "‪C:/Users/Robert/Documents/habitats.txt";

    try {
        File animalFile = new File(animalInfo);
        FileReader animalReader = new FileReader(animalFile);
        BufferedReader animalList = new BufferedReader (animalReader);
        StringBuilder animalDetailList = new StringBuilder();

        String line;

        while ((line = animalList.readLine()) != null) {
            for (i = 0; i <4 ; i++) {
                System.out.println(line);
                animalList.readLine();
            }
        }
        animalReader.close();
        System.out.println(animalDetailList.toString());
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
}
```

So I want to have the output of the animalList class in my main, but I don't know how to bring it over because I'm not necessarily bring over variable, but a process. The full thing should bring the first line and four past it (so a total of the first five lines in the doc). Hopefully that makes things easier to see my problem.

Comment: And your problem is ?

Comment: I don't know how to output the animalDetailList.toString() from the animal class as an output in the main class under the first if section.

Comment: First, you should set a return type on animalDetails() and return what you are printing there. second of all, you should probably make animalDetails() static so that it can be called without having to make an animalList

Comment: `public static String animalDetails () { // all your logic here; return animalDetailList.toString();}`  `public static void main(String[] args) {// all your logic here; System.out.println(animalList.animalDetails());` BTW, the class name should follow camel naming: every letter should starts with capital.

Comment: @Tiina could you show that in the code above? I tried changing the type and putting the return statement, but I'm getting a "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: TL;DR consider posting [mcve]

Comment: @c0der if I edit it will that help? only lets me post once  a day

Comment: yes you can edit

Comment: @c0der just changed it, does that make it easier? I have been smashing my head against  wall for hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of `AnimalList` :

```
public class AnimalList {//use java naming convention

    public void animalDetails () {

        //mcve should be runnable. The problem you ask help with is not
        //reading from file, so remove file reading functionality to make it mcve
        StringBuilder animalDetailList = new StringBuilder();
        animalDetailList.append("Family: Cats").append("\n")
                        .append("Type  : Panther").append("\n")
                        .append("Weight: 250kg").append("\n")
                        .append("Color : Pink");
        System.out.println(animalDetailList.toString());
    }
}
```

Invoke its method from another class:

```
public class FinalRobert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //to invoke animalDetails() method use
        AnimalList aList = new AnimalList();
        aList.animalDetails();

        //if you do not need the aList refrence you could use 
        //new AnimalList().animalDetails();
    }
}
```

Output

> Family: Cats 
> Type  : Panther 
> Weight: 250kg 
> Color :
>   Pink

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalRobert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        animalList list = new animalList();
        list.animalDetails();
    }
}



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


public class animalList {

    public String animalDetails () {

        int i = 0;
        String output="";

        String animalInfo = "C:/Users/Robert/Documents/animals.txt";
        String animalHabitat = "‪C:/Users/Robert/Documents/habitats.txt";

        try {
            File animalFile = new File(animalInfo);
            FileReader animalReader = new FileReader(animalFile);
            BufferedReader animalList = new BufferedReader (animalReader);

            String line;
            while ((line = animalList.readLine()) != null & i<4) {
                   System.out.println(line);
                    output = output + "\n"+ line;
                    i++;
            }
            animalReader.close();
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```